# How to I get Visual Studio Code to treat <webscript> the same way it treats <script>?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m working on HTML files which contain JavaScript inside `<webscript>` tags. Can I customize Visual Studio Code so that it treats these tags the same way it treats `<script>` tags, i.e. with syntax highlighting, etc.?

Comment: Can I ask a stupid question? Why?

Comment: I want syntax highlighting for the JavaScript, keyboard shortcut for comments, snippets and other JavaScript editing features to work in the <webscript> code blocks.

Comment: No, I meant, why are you using non-HTML tags for something a perfectly good HTML tag exists for.

Comment: The software platform I'm using (Huron Click Portal) used the webscript tag to specify JavaScript (its actually Jscript) code which is run server side before the file is returned to the client. They still use the html file extension for these files.

Comment: just to be clear : do you want synax highlighting or do you want script it to transpile webscript to script tags oO

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I want editing features like smart braces, snippits, syntax highlighting, etc. I don't need build features like transpiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to customize this in Code. But you could write your own language configuration. A documentation with a sample file can be found at: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide

The most easiest way would searching for the default html language configuration copy this file and just edit the regex for script to support webscript, too. Should be [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/html)